# indent individual \item in enumerate

Tags: enumerate, indentation

I want to be able to indent individual items in an enumerate environment.
I know about `{\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item Text}`, but this fail when the content of the item breaks into a new line:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[2]
        
        {\setlength\itemindent{25pt} \item \lipsum[2] }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can I indent the whole text of the indented item as well?
[EDIT: Without nesting environments. I would like to have a solution that works dynamically.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom environment that deals with all the counter business (similar to what Dan suggested in his answer, but without the need of messing with the counters in the document itself).
However, you would need a new environment for each layer of indention. This could be achieved by concatenating an additional `i` to each countername.
(i.e. `enumi`->`enumii` and `enumii`->`enumiii` etc.. I demonstrated how that works for the 2nd level of indention)

Heres my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{enumindent}
{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),start=\value{enumi},leftmargin=20pt] \stepcounter{enumii} }
    {\end{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{\value{enumii}}}
\newenvironment{enumindenttwice}
{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),start=\value{enumii},leftmargin=20pt] \stepcounter{enumiii} }
    {\end{enumerate}\setcounter{enumii}{\value{enumiii}}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{enumerate}[(1)]
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \begin{enumindent}
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \begin{enumindenttwice}
                \item \lipsum[2]
                \item \lipsum[2]
            \end{enumindenttwice}
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
        \end{enumindent}
        \item \lipsum[2]
        \item \lipsum[2]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to nest `enumerate` though you will need to update the item counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hang}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate} %<--
\item[2.] \lipsum[2] %<--
\end{enumerate} %<--
\setcounter{enumi}{2} %<--

\item \lipsum[3]

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[2]
        %
        {\setlength\itemindent{0.1\textwidth}
        \item 
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.82\textwidth} % manually adjust width
              \lipsum[2] 
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

with results--

[image: img]